# Contentful UI extension to intercept unpublishing

Tags: content-management-system, contentful, contentful-api

Is there a way to use Contentful’s App framework to intercept the unpublish feature? For example, I’m trying to make it so someone has to specify why they are unpublishing content which then goes to a webhook. Is this possible?

I tried looking at the docs and it doesn’t seem to state how I could override existing the existing of Contentful.